# Is there any way to make an HTTP/2 request with Java 8, without installing ALPN?

Tags: java, http

we're using Java 8, and we need to make HTTP/2 requests. This software is distributed to clients to run on desktop machines, and modifying the boot classpath to include ALPN is not an option.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: I suggest rewording your question to ask for a library with certain features that can operate within the constraints of your environment.